# MongoNetworkError: connection 6 to [connection_url] timed out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongo Connection Config

```
mongoose.connect(mongo.uri, {
    socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
    reconnectTries: 30000,
    connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
    keepAlive: 1,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  });
```

I am trying to insert data using a seeder but my data was very large.
my data file size was 70mb.

The mongo connection URL was my server mongo URL.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: connection 6 to [connection_url] timed out
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:259:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:288:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:432:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
(node:71) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:71) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

if anyone has any idea about this then, please help. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the seeder trying to run before the connection can be established?

Comment: yes, I have established a connection in the start of the seeder file @LenJoseph

Comment: You may have to delay the seeder until the connection is established. I would try turning the connection into a promise, and when the promise resolves initiate the seeder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this error. it was not a perfect solution but its work for me. I have divided my seeder data into multiple chunks and insert it by chunk.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

_.chunk([large Data Object], 500);
```

500 = number of data you want in one chunk

Hope its also work for you!